# Current Item Url for SharePoint 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I need to give the link for current item url in workflow to open a form.

For that I have used

```
[%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%]?OpenIn=Browser
```

But this is not working in SharePoint-2013.

Comment: Are you using SPD2013, and in that platform type of 2013?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SPD 2013 and in that 2013 platform

Comment: Are you trying to send the link of current item in an email?

Comment: Is that a library or list?

Comment: Yes.. I have to send current item link in an email for approval process and it is library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For library, Document URL can be found in

```
EncodedAbsUrl
```

Action should look like

```
Set Variable: url to Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL
```

1. Create a new variable
2. **Data source:** *Current Item*
3. **Field from source:** *Encoded Absolute URL*

[image]

Comment: Thanks but where we can find EncodedAbsUrl in workflow

Comment: Writing details

Comment: Welcome! glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me better while sending email address:

Under workflow: Select **Workflow Context**, then **current item URL**. Shown below

```
****[%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%]****
```

Comment: Be careful when using `[%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%]` The code above gives you the absolute **decoded** url. For example: if your newly added document has a name of "*Document Name With Spaces.doc*", it would have been translated as "http://your.domain.com/subsite/DocumentLibrary/Folder/Document Name With Spaces.doc" You see that link generated maps to somewhere else than it supposed to..

Answer (score 0):

Building on the use of

**Workflow Context**: **current item URL** described above....

When adding the lookup, first add "<" then select "Current Item URL" under "Workflow Context", and follow it with ">".

This will ensure there are no breaks in the link described by Irfan.

Line should look like this

<[%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%]>

Answer (score 0):

What produced the right working URL for my current document library file item in a SharePoint 2013 workflow is:

`[%Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL%]`